# Chef skip directory resource

Tags: chef-infra

I would like to create directory and to give rights.
I have following code in my Chef cookbook

```
directory "/home/user/.ssh" do                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  owner user                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  group user                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  mode '0700'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  recursive true                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  action :create                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
end
```

But the Chef skippes this resource, till I create this directory. As it's created the Chef begans to "see" this block and changes rights for example.

Comment: I tend to say "that can't be true". Are you running chef-client as `root` user?

Comment: No, simple user w/o sudo.
UPD: No, this is kitchen, so user is kitchen with sudo rights.

Comment: If you mean you are running this inside a Kitchen test, the behavior you are seeing does not match what Chef does. Please include the output from Chef, at log_level debug if you can.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hjpH7EXU